# Math arithmetic

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

So I got this question in my exam yesterday, and only a few people from my school could solve this.

What's so hard about it? I have learned the simple arithmetic questions, but I don't really understand how to do this one.

formulas:

[image]

In the arithmetic the tenth organ is 4 times bigger than the  third organ.

The amount of all first 50 organs is 3725.
Find A1 and D (the first and the difference of the series).

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You write the equations for the 10th term, and 3rd term:

$T_n = a + (n-1)d$

$T_3 = a + (3-1)d = a + 2d$

$T_{10} = a + (10-1)d = a + 9d$

You are told that $T_{10}$ is 4 times $T_3$, or that: $T_{10} = 4T_{3}$

Which means:

$a + 9d = 4(a + 2d)$

And lastly, the sum all the first 50 terms is 3725, which means:

$S_n = \dfrac{n(2a+(n-1)d)}{2}$

$S_{50} = \dfrac{50(2a+(50-1)d)}{2} = 3725$

You should be able to solve those.